# Parse string to JArray in C# with method as property

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am storing JSON data in a SQL DB which returns a string, and I need to convert it to a JArray in C#. A property of one of the properties is not a string or number, but a method name and it throws an exception because JArray can't parse it. How do I process this correctly since that value cannot be enclosed in a string quotes and it won't work.

This is the JSON:

```
 {
      "id": "4",
      "data": [
    {     
      wrappers: ['floating-label'],     
      fieldGroup: [{
        key: 'town',
        type: 'input',
        templateOptions: {
          required: true,
          placeholder: "Your town",
         
        },
      }],
    },
    {
      key: 'Connection',
      type: 'select',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Connection',
        options: this.dataservice.getModels(),
        valueProp: 'id',
        labelProp: 'name',
      },
    },
  ]
}
```

My current code after getting the JSON from the DB: in a select

```
var resultArray =  JArray.FromObject(result.Select(e => JObject.Parse(e.Form)).ToArray());
```

Is there a way to convert to JArray or a JSON object, and still keep the value for options in the JSON above as is?

Comment: `but a method name and it throws an exception` What was the exception? Also, it would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: JSON can’t have method calls like that, so you won’t be able to parse it with any standard library. You’ll need to write your own parser. I strongly recommend you come up with a different approach that does involve code in your data.

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ says that is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Do not confuse JSON and JavaScript: your sample looks as JavaScript. JSON requires double-quotes only for strings and for field names (as in the beginning of your sample).
Moreover, JSON allows only strings, numbers, and booleans.

Read the specs [here](https://json.org).